# xCode - Add SSL Certificate to iOs Profile (Programmatically)

Tags: ios, xcode, ssl, certificate, installation

To test my app I have manually added two SSL certificates in my iPhone Profile, but users can not do it, how can I install profiles via code?

The manual process was:

1. Send to me the certificates by mail
2. Open
3. Tap on Install button

Now I see them certificates in Settings >> General >> Profiles

any ideas? better if you have a code (Swift is better, but is not problem Obj-C)

Comment: No reply for my ask?

Answer (score 4):

I think the first question is, do you need to install the profiles programmatically, or do you simply need to be able to trust your self-signed / private SSL certificates?  If the latter, then when you're doing your SSL connection request, you can choose to do the validation yourself (implement a delegate for [connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDelegate/connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:)).  Then you simply keep the public cert within your application itself and load the data into the SecTrustRef which you'll do in evaluating the server connection.

HTH.

Comment: Well the question is simple, you can install an SSL certificate into keychain  (iOS trust store) by mailing it to yourself and saving it to the keychain, 
So how would you do this programmatically from an App

Comment: If you're set on adding it into the keychain, you would do so with a SecItemAdd call (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/#//apple_ref/c/func/SecItemAdd), but note that this will only allow you to add it to the application keychain; not the user's default truststore.  I don't believe there's way to do the latter, as Apple is isolating that from applications as part of a defense-in-depth strategy against rogue applications which sneak through the vetting process.  If you just want to validate web calls, I would stick with validation above.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll award you the bounty...
Anyways I was just wondering that is there any way to do it in an unconventional or illegitimate way.
You can even msg me personally Let me know if you can help.